# Windows Toolbar + Google Chrome: Display all tabs on hover

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1

So I'm a big fan of Google Chrome on Windows 8.1, IE just doesn't cut it for me (popular opinion I believe...)

The ONLY advantage I see in IE over Chrome is the hover display on the windows toolbar.

(Sorry the images are from windows 7...)

[image: (Sorry the images are from windows 7...)]

Where on chrome with three tabs open...

[image]
<sub>(source: [askvg.com](http://media.askvg.com/articles/images/Windows_7_Taskbar_Thumbnails.png))</sub>

Does anyone know of a way to get Google Chrome to operate as Internet Explorer does on the toolbar?

Maybe some kind of chrome extension I am unaware of, but who knows! Thanks for any help, maybe we can solve this problem for good!